# How do I make a type-level list of varying Generics in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given this type:

```ts
type AThingWithGenerics<A, B, C> = {
  name: string;
  someFunction: (id: number) => A;
  anotherFunction: () => B;
  loveSomeGenerics: (s: string) => { foo: C };
};
```

Where `A`, `B`, and `C` are objects that vary across values. For example:

```
const aThing: AThingWithGenerics<{ foo: string }, { foo: number, bar: string }, { bar: string }> = {
  name: "a_thing",
  someFunction: (id: number) => { return { foo: "bar" }; },
  anotherFunction: () => { return { foo: 3, bar: "foo" } },
  loveSomeGenerics: (s: string) => { return { foo: { bar: "In this case C is an object containing a string" + s } }; },
}

const anotherThing: AThingWithGenerics<{ bar: number }, { aString: string }, { bar: "test" }> = {
  name: "another_thing",
  someFunction: (id: number) => { return { bar: id + 1 }; },
  anotherFunction: () => { return { aString: "test" } },
  loveSomeGenerics: (s: string) => { return { foo: { bar: "test" } } },
}
```

It's possible to create a tuple of specific `AThingWithGenerics`:

```
type ASpecificPileOfThings = [typeof aThing, typeof anotherThing];
```

It's also possible to make a list of `AThingWithGenerics` as long as `A`, `B`, and `C` do not vary:

```
type APileOfTheSameThing<A, B, C> = [AThingWithGenerics<A, B, C>];
```

But I am trying to add a list of related `AThingWithGenerics` to `AThingWithGenerics`, so `aThing` might include `[anotherThing]` as its `related`. The problem is `A`, `B`, and `C` in `related` will vary.

So how do I create a type that contains varying generics? This is what I have so far:

```
type AThingWithGenericsII<A, B, C> = {
  name: string;
  someFunction: (id: number) => A;
  anotherFunction: () => B;
  loveSomeGenerics: (s: string) => { foo: C };
  related: Array<AThingWithGenericsII<A,B,C>>
}

const anotherThingWithRelated: AThingWithGenericsII<{ bar: number }, { aString: string }, { bar: "test" }> = {
  name: "another_thing",
  someFunction: (id: number) => { return { bar: id + 1 } },
  anotherFunction: () => { return { aString: "test" } },
  loveSomeGenerics: (s: string) => { return { foo: { bar: "test" } } },
  related: []
}

const aThingWithRelated: AThingWithGenericsII<{foo: string, bar: string }, { property: string }, { nestedFoo: number }> = {
  name: "a_thing_with_related",
  someFunction: (id: number) => { return { foo: "This is a string", bar: "" } },
  anotherFunction: () => { return { property: "bar" } },
  loveSomeGenerics: (s: string) => { return { foo: { nestedFoo: 3.1 } } },
  related: [anotherThingWithRelated]
}
```

This does not typecheck, since `A`, `B`, and `C`s types do not unify. How can `AThingWithGenericsII` be changed so `aThingWithRelated` type checks?

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggKgCwJYDsDmB1JwEHEIoQBOSAxgM4A8MANFAEJ0DCAfFALxQDeAsAFBQoKAIYBbCAC4o5YCXQBufoPIB7cQDEArilLAkKlFIAUSACZSUm0QCNiASg5sYigVGEoVOYlp16Dxh3Y2ehdBABsVADcIAGU1CHxCEgpjcikZOTRAti4oADMVFSkmKABfF3L%20flIDGTdEVDQpeGR0LBxE4jIqXIKi6VlGsrpewosrWyI6a2EidMH0Ye4oGbmBzLK2Tl5XEXEpACJhAH0cRoOaJWl4n119QygTcyEJ%200dloghgTSIUZb7DqsDmVhld3J4EN5tHd-I9sh8vj8-qN%20gBmaazQ59YGlUGuCLROLiTrJNKPMkZRrw3Kfb6-f5jZarQ4AST%20Z3IUFIwnI0BKSE57igKmsACsILouQZgMJUENhOtzlAANTSEHlPGlKp8GooOrgrxEBroZrGzDYPAELoUSi5ZkvGzEJa5YQxBZNRWLUojFaYqAHYAQGQ4rbcK57ST%20g2QoinVpoC5XVQaaF%20B5PcaOojUqC0pFMv1mFVQACM6surmjUN89wC7xpiPpLrdmUOgeD5auBNi8RJ3VS80yObzTfyjLtfoDQeAOM7fC1fH4oEgsBikFISDyZAACkgwhAAPJ5M2czgAbWXEBUeXq8bol%20vbg8hrNAF0XEvwNAYLv90fELEYgQGa1B0IwUCsBwUBnlcLSNO0lpJN0oEMMwLD8O%202qXrAZoIX2FAsiyKHgZB2zhkBg6NKE1wpjWsIZg6kzws4YLPjGtxpnWQQMNR3ZEgkVqkgOnpZPWY79CUlSuJ8YTCIGzxnnBbQWvh5CEaBjCsK%20-ALtUtTALe8EWgAShAsnyaa8Z4YJ3TqVwAIiRiayUl6PpgEQKiQEQoCUa5yyEDIECmOojKWFmmxQTsggRocJxnOgxwAO4WscMlyUFiauMmEAcbWjxmJmTFiSOyLiYcDScgKbgiRcvprAcs7eqxELVjC6bDo2pXuZ5xA%20f6QJzuEUQ9sSNkpOSvmidxDZ0qVDm5AF8khWiAB0Za4htFaCGlFnQcIZp0FWRrxtp85AA). I'm sure [this question about recursive Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079301/how-to-use-typescript-generics-recursively) is related, but I couldn't get it to work for my case.

Comment: `[AThingWithGenericsII<A,B,C>]` doesn't mean an array of those things - it means a tuple of length 1, with one of those things. So you're going to get a type error just from trying to have an array with two elements in your object.

Comment: @kaya3 should be fixed now, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the first interface `AThingWithGenerics` you have defined but with this added in, you do not need the others :

```
type AThingWithGenerics<A = any, B = any, C = any> = {
  name: string;
  someFunction: (id: number) => A;
  anotherFunction: () => B;
  loveSomeGenerics: (s: string) => { foo: C };

  // some things might not have relatives
  related?: Array<AThingWithGenerics>
};
```

Using type `any` with the generic definitions will make typescript infer the types of generics used in a specific instance. We do this to allow the `related` property to use any generics that will ultimately be inferred by typescript.

Just to add the sentiment behind the interface, I figured not all "things" will be related so that is why it is possibly `undefined`, which was the initial `ts` error found on the link you provided.

[Playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggKgCwJYDsDmB1JwEHEIoQBOSAxgM4A8MUAvFAIYogA0UAQnY82wMJdMQAPi4BvALAAoKFBQMAthABcUcsBLoA3FJnkA9ooBiAVxSlgSPShUAKJABMVKY-IBGxAJR0RMbdO56OMQmZhZWtl60Iux+MgA2egBuEADKBhD4hCQUtuQqahpokSKiUABmenoq-AC+sVAA9A2q6VA4qORQ8khoCMCygVAIDMlQRBBxDBbJ5DpjE1MQ9gD8KjBERAwg1IiomNh4BMRk5EJSdVJSTW0IBFAA7tCkTEMj0EHlenEJ93tSpFY1Iw1rt0FgcJljhRKKUKlVVOo9lAamxYZUnC53EQ2K4GER8oj0MjUVBcfiEYVkSJ6BJ-HJFCoAEQMAD67XQjJYc30RlM5ks1igdkcskxnm8UFK42AxiIKEln3hjLJjORxLmTECtyIIX54SFxQV0tl8rR8IAzDi8Uy4aqaur-AlkmlFJDsnkhR6CntDVKIDK5Qq4SpSmSmQBJeXtTrPcjQfhITovPSuABWEHMUABKGADFQSIYFL2qoA1Ko1XUHTV-oD+q4QcgwQc3ScYaTraK3MRiQqGClCWgCZSUQqw1BGcAIGo7dTJXN6cpx5qgkQ2Y20JzueldWFBcKMV2iL75gHTe3yQ4oGWAIwVrn+ZfancCiISv2n3v9wpMyfTu9zJ1UnSFsck9IcfTfE8TSDdFRw7Ccp2AO1-0katJCuZognleQGAAa3eW55HmSZJzaPQsxrFAgVIBs9nBQ4slbURgyLdArXJb0iRHUowCIPRICIUBwK4klCDUJZDFg5xDypMR5wURdmTXPYWV+HAWXGEilk3fweQgZ99X3TssWPY1AzNJldk6RNGFYjd2KZZCUQ1FAtWCPld1fKIjX9aCeL4gShPHFUUPiJIgNdI53VyYSikgsyzxY0oxMnexJItAA6W97Ry+8ZE0xYRQAbQYHEAF1zkuSRriwh53kQh4DizUkQCgNB-QsIkPnGMpiAIUhoD0MooGwToCtS8okAmewMtmgBiVzSIAWmamyIAADzAOIyGwOIQAw2BQX2CEorIKBjHIJFyEgUgkDKM7J3kLbFk6fRiMKxrvlJd5wCWRhOjAPRyEu1w9vOlB7Age7CBmqQ7psUgMvGpYvFpGRsyBewuER5H7CKgAGMr6muN7HlUBA9GMOIsY2m7+hwKYoCxmyGDmDGvggDKEjQGwsdofnGA8TRGkwohjAgPKoDma4yd+L77Ep0GnluUhcO4LGATAVrC2AciIDZ2soGgGkoFmjLCwufx2biTnuZsY36AYIWRfKBg4jjSr0Oq5pE3IcXOhWkBKazJhFqNzbttu4AwYun7IG4Vq1IQG5oHaxjSG+55Y5G-o5biEPs9ASByFIEgwGAA7dZGlBeqIG5GY+NOoRGpNmBT+Ug+MT78-a-oXiQJ7I+wBOjY2PQiAyoA)

Comment: I'm sorry about the TS error. You are correct, not all things will be related. I've updated my code (and the playground code) to fix the error, do my changes affect your answer at all?

Comment: No not at all, for varying generics, using ts inference is a solution. if the solution answers your question correctly, please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Thought you would probably say that, but also thought I had better check! Thanks for the clarification and the answer, I think this is a good solution.