# Assign a predefined generic type to a class method declared with arrow function

Tags: typescript, generics, arrow-functions

**EDITED**:

As @jcalz mentioned, my comment lacked of simple example so there is a [live here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiMWACwPYBMA8AVAfFAvFABQCGAXFFgJQF5ZQA+UArgHZoQBmAlqxGgG4AUEIDGAGxIBnKbBABhSTKgBvIVA1QA9FqgAJFAHcowFFDAAnCFIgWAbtADmEPhe6j1msMwBG491BSwCTAAWjcUmCSIBRwCMjo2HiEpDT4eGqaWVCiKKxSKOIQAHTiKI5EAEQkBFCVADRQJFTC2ZpWwMwWrE2tmgC+QoNCOlAAMiG2InCK0lLF4ZHRGEFurI44VQBMlS1CM0rzi1EkIBiszAC2PrabAIwtQA)

Bellow is the content

```
type MyMethod<T> = (a: T) => T | undefined;

class MyClass {
    // How to preserve generic ??
    public static display: MyMethod<T> = (a) => {
        console.log("a = ", a);
        return a;
    }
}

// Later

MyClass.display<string>("2");
MyClass.display<number>(1);
```

**OLD**:

I have a predefined type (for reusability) which I want it to be assigned to a class method declared with arrow function

```
export type RowDataTreefiedType<T extends object> = {
   tableData: { path: number[], childRows: RowDataTreefiedType<T>[]}
};

export type UpdateDataByPath<T extends object> = (
    // The path of the item we're trying to update
    path: RowDataTreefiedType<T>['tableData']['path'],

    // The new data
    newData: RowDataTreefiedType<T>,

    // Whether to update child or not
    updateChildren?: boolean,

    // Callback to apply on each child to get the data
    updateChildrenCallback?: (child: RowDataTreefiedType<T>) => RowDataTreefiedType<T>
) => void;
```

Later in my class I want the type of `updateDataByPath` method to be `UpdateDataByPath` and **preserve the generic**.

```
class TreefyTable {
   // There's an error here with T
   updateDataByPath: UpdateDataByPath<T> = (path, newData, updateChildren, updateChildrenCallback) => {
       /// ...
   }

}
```

So that I could call like this

```
type User = {name: string; id: number};

//...

table.updateDataByPath<User>(path, newItem, true, (child) => {
   // the main goal is to have both child.name, child.id and child.tableData be defined

};
```

But typescript shows error on the declaration of the method.

I even tried

```
updateDataByPath: <T extends object>UpdateDataByPath<T> = (path, newData, updateChildren, updateChildrenCallback) => {

}
```

but no way.

Please how could I achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Typescript generics recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079301/how-to-use-typescript-generics-recursively)

Comment: @jsejcksn No because with dealing with a class method and above all declared the arrow way

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wQ5VVw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz I'm sure that making a reproductible example is needed since it address a general Typescript issue which is how to deal with generic on class method declared with arrow functions. The code I wrote is just 'an example of case'

Comment: But if it could help I'll provide one

Comment: "I'm sure that making a reproducible example is needed" Is there supposed to be a "not" in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it would definitely help.  The code you have is probably close, but there's at least one issue with it which makes it hard to see what's going on: `RowDataTreefiedType` isn't currently generic at all, so every use of `RowDataTreeifiedType<T>` is an error. I assume you are not trying to ask about that.

Comment: Your example is using `string` which does not extend `object`, and a type named `int` which does not exist.  Assuming you don't need `extends object` and you mean `number` instead of `int` (and if you do, please [edit] the question to fix that so that the answer doesn't need to mention it), the solution would be to change the scope of the generic type parameter `T` so that it's on the call signature and not the type name, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVaZBw).  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz you're focusing too much on the example rather than seeing the underlined problem. But I edited again to make more clair

Comment: And does [the solution I presented above](https://tsplay.dev/NVaZBw) where you change the scope of the generic type parameter work for you?  If so, I can answer the question.  If not, then please tell me what about that doesn't work.