# Union of all possible generics

Tags: typescript

I have the following recursive structure:

```js
interface ElementTyped<T> {
    label: string;
    get: () => T;
    set: (v: T) => void;
};

interface Section {
    label: string;
    elements: Element[];
};

type Element = ElementTyped<any> | Section;
```

Currently, I do not get type checking for `Element<T>` - which is in fact always an `Element<any>`. Does anyone see any way to get type checking for it? In particular is there any way to make a union of all possible types like this (imaginary syntax):

```js
type Element = ElementTyped<all> | Section;
```

Just to let you now, there is a rather elaborate solution for recursive generics here: [How to use Typescript generics recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079301/how-to-use-typescript-generics-recursively) that renders the type very cumbersome to use.

Comment: The generic means that it can be anything, you just need to substitute the given type into the generic.  Perhaps you want to replace the `any` with `unknown` to force you to ensure that your code is valid when it depends on the structure of the generic type `T`?

Comment: This is not really possible if `T` is not given any constraints.

Comment: You're looking for [*existentially quantified generic types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), which behave like infinite unions.  Unfortunately TypeScript lacks direct support for such types (most languages with generics also lack this feature, though).  You can emulate them, but it might make things more cumbersome than you want.

Comment: Please demonstrate how you plan to use a value of type `Element` so I can advise.  If `T` can truly be any type, then the only safe thing you can do with one (that isn't a `Section`) would be `element.set(element.get())`... so I'm curious what value such a type would be to you.   On the other hand if `T` is actually constrained to some finite union of known types (e.g., `string | number | boolean | ...`) then we can do something else.  If you can edit the question with a [mre] including some use cases I might have suggestions.

Comment: @jcalz Currently I am using 4 different types with separate implementations for `string | number | boolean | enum` and it is mostly the `enum` that would greatly benefit from this - because I can have an infinite number of enums

Comment: I'm not understanding how the enum part works; could you show an implementation of an `"ElementTyped<enum>"` and/or a function that processes one of them? It still seems to me like you either need some finite set of known enums or you can't really do much useful with them.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/mmomtchev/react-native-settings-screen/blob/main/src/index.tsx This is a public API, `SettingsElementEnum` would benefit from being able to have the `enum` type on its setter/getter instead of a generic `string`